# Difference between using X.push(?) or X[index] =?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to create an `array (X)` of known length in javascript.  What is the difference between using `X.push(??)` or `X[index] = ??` to populate my array? The results seem to be the same, but are there any differences?

edit: thanks for the responses. I probably should have been more specific in querying the differences.  When using X.push function (adding to the end of the array) would there be any issues in terms of memory/time when doing this with an array that is very large compared to allocating space for a very large array and just setting an index to a value?

Comment: You should use `Array(desiredLength)`. Also you may want to look at [the spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.push) which in this case is very readable even if you otherwise don't look at it at all.

Answer (score 4):

In X.push(), you need not to worry about the index. The push() function will automatically push the element serially from index 0-n position.
But in X[index], you need to specifically define the index where you need to put the value in array at which index.

Answer (score 1):

by using  `X[index]= ??`

every time you need assign position index value

in this assignment   `X.push(??)`

no need to worry about position of index. we can directly assign data element

Answer (score 1):

99% of the times for adding a new element to an array you use push.

Usually you dont add elements with x[index] cause you mess with the natural sequence on your array.

most of the times x[index] used when you what to edit or get the specific element of the array eg. on a function you pass the index

```
function doSomethingWithSpecificElement(index){
    //x[index] usage (edit or anything)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

when we write`X[index]=` means we set a value to a particular index.
when we write `X.push(??)` means we put value without known position

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on the precise value of `index`.

When using `array.push(value);`, the value will be appended to the end of the array without altering other values in the array. The result is similar to using `array[array.length] = value;`.

```
var X = [ 1 ];

X.push(2);       // `length` becomes 2; 2 appended after 1
console.log(X);  // [ 1, 2 ]

X[X.length] = 3; // `length` becomes 3; 3 appended after 2
console.log(X);  // [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

Beyond that, `array[index] = value;` assigns a value to a specific index (property), regardless of whether it already had a value or not:

```
X[0] = 99;      // `length` still 3; 1 replaced
console.log(X); // [ 99, 2, 3 ]

X[4] = 77;      // `length` becomes 5; gap created at 4th
console.log(X); // [ 99, 2, 3, undefined, 77]
```

In either case, the array's `length` will increase as needed to remain 1 over the largest index.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple things here. Let's talk about the first scenario here which is `X[index] = 'something';`

Over here, you can mention the `index` and it will assign the value in that particular index of an array. But there is a catch here. For example, consider the following code

```
var t = ['hello'];
t[21] = ['world'];
```

Though you will assume that there are only two elements in the array, it will just return you `2` as the length, instead, this will return `22` as it creates empty array elements too between 0 to 20.

Also, if you pass the wrong index, it will override the value if there's any in the said index.

---

If you use [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) you don't need to specify any index IF you want to push the element to the end of the array. It knows the length and will APPEND the new element to the end of the array. But there's not much you can do here. It will always push the new element to the end of the array. Similarly, if you want to prepend an element to the start of the array, you can use [`.unshift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift)